# Calculating the price of product before increase in price by 30%?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, percentages

Problem to solve:

To buy 2 products the seller gives 30% discount for the **less expensive** product. The customer/buyer payed for both products 300$. What is the biggest/max price of the less expensive product before the 30% discount?

What I did:

let **x** be the first product

let **y** be the second product which is lowered by 30%, the less expensive 
product

*First equation:* $x+y-(y*0.3)=300{$}$

*Second equation **?*** I tried but just did a modification of the previous one which is incorrect. Also would derivatives apply here?
$$$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown that
$$x+\frac{7}{10}y=300$$
and so
$$x=300-\frac{7}{10}y$$
and, in order for $y$ to be less expensive,
$$y \lt x$$
by substitution,
$$y \lt 300-\frac{7}{10}y$$
$$\frac{17}{10}y \lt 300$$
$$y \lt \frac{3000}{17} \approx 176.48$$
and so there is no *real* maximum value of $y$, since it cannot equal or exceed $\approx \$176.48$ but can be any value arbitrarily close to it and less than it.

The inequality
$$y \lt x$$
was really the "second equation" that you were looking for, but it isn't an equation.

Comment: damn, so easy when you showed it. Tnx. Would overload my mind too much If I hadn't asked the question.

Comment: @eugensunic No problem, don't worry about it. If it helped, just $\checkmark$! :D

Comment: I'm waiting for the interval to pass to +15, already +10 !

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question.

Here's a more direct approach.

The maximum pre-discount price $y^*$ of $Y$ (the less expensive product) must be equal to $x$, the price of $X$ (the more expensive product).

If ${y^*}'$ is the maximum post-discount price of $Y$, then   ${y^*}':x=7:10$ which gives
$$y^*=x=\frac {10}{17}\cdot 300=\color{red}{176.47}$$

Comment: Nice approach, but $\frac{3000}{17} = 176.47$ to the nearest hundredth.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig - Thanks for pointing out the typo! :)